# How to automate API testing with SoapUi and Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, soapui

We are building a test automation framework in spring boot. I have both Rest and Soap service which need to be mocked and load test the whole application.

For mocking some services i know that i can use SoapUi GUI and see the response same to the API test. but i want to automated and integrated SoapUi through spring boot and automate those functionalities through code base.

Did anyone has any experience on this? 
Resource materials to refer?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to write a test script for SOAP UI which would contain all API calls that will be executed when you run your tests provided your server is UP.

Comment: @VishwaRatna .  Yes i know that but the problem how to integrate soapUi with spring boot?  does SoapUi has maven dependencies? or plugging?

Comment: Try the SoapUI site for help.... E.g. https://www.soapui.org/soapui-for-ide/eclipse/eclipse-plugin.html